# Inserting google map's script into html webpage

Tags: javascript, css, html

I was asked to edit webpage for my friend. I am not an IT specialist or computer master, but I can do some edits in html, php and js.

I am trying to add the google's map script to [this webpage](http://biegsgh.pl/), you can find the code here: http://pastebin.com/UDNZ4F4r.
The thing is that if I copy and paste all of this it does work on my page, but in ruins the whole design (style from the script applies to everything).
 I figured out that it's because of the `< style >.....< / style >` line, but the script just won't work without this fragment.
Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem? That is to say to include the script without ruining the style of the webpage.

Comment: Where is the site hosted? How are you copy-pasting the data exactly?

Comment: you'll probably need to share a link to the website or some code to get a good response. you can always update your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link you posted, it looks like it is the style selectors for html and body, as it is setting the height to 100%, which is probably messing up your layout. Try removing them from the selector, and give the map the height and width you want and see if it works:

```
    <style>
      #map-canvas {
        height: 500px;
        width:400px
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
```

The reason the map would not work without it was that it had no height, thus it did not appear on the page.

Comment: My bad, of course there should be <style > not < div style=...>, I copied the wrong pastebin. Here is the right one http://pastebin.com/UDNZ4F4r. Problem is not about code, the problem is how to insert it on the webpage? Because when I copy this code which I pasted on pastebin to my index.html file it ruins the whole design.

Comment: Well then, post a link to the website, or create a jsfiddle so we can test it with your actual website's coding

Comment: It works, thank you very much. I knew something was wrong about body, but I didn't know how to edit it. That was more difficult for me, while for you it was a piece of cake. Thank for your time mate.